# remove string perl with first or last word is in a list

Tags: regex, string, perl

I try to delete all strings if their first or last word is one of this list of words : "the
i
in
there
this
with
on
we
that
of"

For example if i have this string in an input file "with me" this  string will be removed,

Example:
***input***

```
"the european union"


"would like to"

"would like"

"of the european"

"the european parliament"

"the member states"
```

***output***

```
"would like to"

"would like"
```

I've got this idea which seems to me a little bit difficult :

```
my @small = qw(the i in there this with on we that of);
my $small_re = join "|", @small;
$small_re = qr(^(?:$small_re)|(?:$small_re)$);
if ($sequence !~ /$small_re/) {
#...
}
```

Any other idea please?

Thank you

Comment: What is difficult about that? A different solution would be to use a hash to check the words, but then you have to consider case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=the|i|in|there|this|with|on|we|that|of).*$|^(?=.*(?:the|i|in|there|this|with|on|we|that|of)$).*$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/42

Comment: This will allow partial matches, e.g. `these` or `motion`.

Comment: Also, it does not really add anything to what the OP already has. You have only expanded his `$small_re` variable, added look-ahead assertions (quite redundant here) and anchors (also quite redundant).

Comment: @vks, thank you for your help.. As im a beginner in a perl, can you help me please how to add this expression in a perl script? thanks

Comment: @user17241 Did you accept the answer before you had tried it? It will do nothing different than the regex you already have.

Comment: @user17241 use `\b` in each token to make it absolute and use perl replace.

Comment: This off site tool is useful but I think answers with links to regex101.com need more explanation **in the text** or they risk being "link only" answers like any other.